# How can I bootstrapify a table whose columns should not be broken up?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I am creating an HTML table in C# like so:

```
int quadCheck = -1;
int rowNum = 0;
foreach (ProduceUsage puRec in puList)
{
    builder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

    quadCheck++;
    rowNum++;
    // Print the Description on the first iteration of every four rows
    if ((quadCheck.Equals(0)) || (quadCheck % 4 == 0))
    {
        rowNum = 1;
        builder.Append("<td rowspan=\"4\" class=\"description\">");
        builder.Append(puRec.ItemDescription.ToUpper());
        builder.Append("</td>");
    }

    if (rowNum.Equals(PACKAGES))
    {
        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(DATA_ROWLET1_TOTAL_PACKAGES);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth1);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth2);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth3);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth4);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth5);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth6);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth7);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth8);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth9);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth10);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth11);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth12);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PackagesMonth13);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append("Calc later");
        builder.Append("</td>");
    }    
    else if (rowNum.Equals(PURCHASES))
    {
        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(DATA_ROWLET2_TOTAL_PURCHASES);
        builder.Append("</td>");

        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(puRec.PurchasesMonth1);
        builder.Append("</td>");
        . . .
```

It displays on my desktop's browser (Chrome) like so:

[image]

On a punier device, though (tablet or, egads!, a phone) the user would need a magnifying glass to read the data if the aspect ratio were retained - or should I say, if each row remaind together on one line.

I think the data would be too difficult to grok if broken up over multiple lines. OTOH, it's too hard to see on a puny device if simply shrunken.

Is there a way to boostrapify a table such as this, so that it is both retains its semantic clarity as well as its visual legibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Include the Bootstrap css and js files in your html page.
2. Add `class="table"` to your `table`
3. Wrap your table in a `div` with `class="table-responsive"`
4. Profit from a table that will have a scrollbar when viewed on small
   devices

Comment: A horizontal scrollbar I take it?

Comment: Correct, horizontal scrollbars will appear when the table is wider than the viewport.